# Simple Select statement is not working using PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select a `user id` (`uID`) just to check if it exists... I am getting stuck at just the most basic select statement...

I've searched and tried different people's code but either my code always returns true (if i dont use fetch) or it says that it is not an object and i cant not use fetch....

```
$sql = 'SELECT uID FROM ldc_user_details where uID=3';
$q = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$i=$q->execute();

     foreach ($i->fetch() as $key => $val){
      echo 'key='.$key." val =".$val;
     }

ERROR: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/pdwdev/public_html/ldc_main.php
```

Comment: it must be `$q->fetch()`

Comment: On top of posted answers and comments, bear in mind you are doing a query without parameters, therefore `prepare` is useless. You can do `$result = $this->db->query($sql)->fetchAll();` and have all the records in the `$result` array.

Comment: May I ask the reason for assigning ``$i=$q->execute();`` ?

Comment: @Yousuf Memon: Since i dont know what was failing i tried to tear it down to just delete strings that could be the reason of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$sql = 'SELECT uID FROM ldc_user_details where uID=3';

// no need to use prepare() here unless there's a user input

$q = $this->db->query($sql);

// a check for rowCount would be good
if ($q->rowCount() > 0) {

    // all results will be in $i
    $i = $q->fetchAll();

     foreach ($i as $key => $val){

         echo "Key : {$key} <br> Val : {$val}";
     }
}
else {
    die("Zero Results returned");
}
```

?>

Comment: Thank you. It works. but when it is true it returns "key=0 val =Array" i know its fixed by making another foreach loop... but is that the right way?

Answer (score 4):

You need to call fetch on `$q`, not `$i`. `execute` returns a boolean value indicating success or failure.

```
 if($i){ //indicates whether the query succeeded
     foreach ($q->fetchAll() as $key => $val){
         echo 'key='.$key." val =".$val;
     }
 }
```

Note that I am using `fetchAll` to get all rows. `fetch` will return just one, and advance the pointer to the next row.